# resetting attributes in Java Faces

Tags: java, jsf

I've added some code to validate fields in a javafaces site:

```
<h:outputLabel value="Password:"></h:outputLabel>
<h:inputSecret id="password" binding="#{password}" value="#{register.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="Password field must be filled in"></h:inputSecret>
<h:outputLabel value="Repeat password:"></h:outputLabel>
<h:inputSecret id="password2" required="true" requiredMessage="Repeat password field must be filled in">
    <f:validator validatorId="sameValueValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="value" value="#{password.value}"/>
    <f:attribute name="message" value="Passwords do not match"/>
</h:inputSecret>
```

The first time the form is submitted the right attribute value is passed to the validator. The following times though the value is the same as the first value, regardless of what the user types into the fields. Any idea how to reset it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`<h:inputSecret id="password2" required="true" requiredMessage="Repeat password field must be filled in">
    <f:validator validatorId="sameValueValidator"/>
    <f:attribute name="value" value="#{password.value}"/>
    <f:attribute name="message" value="Passwords do not match"/>
</h:inputSecret>`

I suppose you should make immediate "true" for inputSecret

Comment: That won't help at all. It would validate the 2nd field before the 1st field and thus `#{password.value}` would be `null` on 1st submit.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine and is supposed to work fine, assuming that your validator is properly implemented. The symptom of getting the previously submitted value of the 1st password field should only occur when you leave that field **empty**. That's because you're passing `#{password.value}` which would contain the previous value when validation fails. You should instead pass `#{password.submittedValue}`, but that would in turn contain `null` when the validation succeeds.

If you really get the previous value when you enter something else in the field, then it's likely a bug caused by something else than what you've shown as far in your question. Perhaps in the JSF implementation, or by something else in your code. Perhaps you're using `<f:ajax>` on the command button and not re-rendering the input fields.